# Are there any existing problems that wouldn't be solvable with a halting oracle?

Tags: computability, undecidability, halting-problem, oracle-machines

I understand that most problems are trivial if a halting oracle is available (or, I think equivalently, hyper-computation). However, applying the argument that shows the Halting Problem is impossible for a Turing machine also shows that it is impossible for a Turing+oracle to decide the Halting Problem for a Turing+oracle. Are there any actual, practical, examples of problems unsolvable by a halting oracle?

Note: by "oracle" I mean oracle for a standard Turing machine, *not* a TM with an oracle itself.

Comment: There *are* "arbitrarily undecidable" problems, see e.g. [here](http://cs.stackexchange.com/a/4871/98). I don't know about "practical" examples (which also does not match the title you chose); what qualifies as "practical" for you?

Comment: That aren't contrived simply to answer this question. I acknowledged that the next-level halting problem still applies.

Comment: In addition, all languages that are not recursively enumerable are not be reducible to HALT.  Examples include FINITE, EMPTY, whether two CFG's derive the same language, etc.

Answer (score 17):

Just take a problem whose [Turing degree](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Turing_degree) is above $0'$, which is the degree of The Halting Oracle. In terms of the [arithmetical hierarchy](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Arithmetical_hierarchy) you want problems which are above $\Sigma^0_1$. Examples of such problems (where $\phi_n$ is the $n$-th partial computable function and $W_n = \{k \in \mathbb{N} \mid \text{$\phi_n(k)$ is defined}\}$ is the $n$-th computably enumerable set):

- $\{n \in \mathbb{N} \mid \text{$\varphi_n$ terminates for finitely many inputs}\}$ is $\Sigma^0_2$-complete.
- $\{n \in \mathbb{N} \mid \text{$\varphi_n$ is a total function}\}$ is $\Pi^0_2$-complete.
- $\{n \in \mathbb{N} \mid \text{$W_n$ is a computable set}\}$ is $\Sigma^0_3$-complete.

None of these can be solved even if you have a Halting Oracle. For instance, consider the second example, "is $\varphi_n$ total?" Given $n$ how would the Halting Oracle help us decide whether the Turing machine encoded by $n$ halts on *every* input?

---

**[Added 2014-06-03]** For a "practical" aspect of all of this, consider the problem: a programmer has written a function `void charge_credit_card(int card_number, int amount)` and we would like to know whether the function terminates on all inputs. It is *impossible* to write a compiler which can automatically check this in general. Moreover, even if we allow the compiler to ask us questions of the form "does `charge_credit_card` terminate when given input `(k,m)`?", it is still impossible.

Comment: Can you give a scenario where someone might actually ask such a question? Also, I don't really understand the example.

Comment: @ike You may have to learn to live with the fact that not all of (computer) science, and arguably even less of TCS/mathematics has practical applications *now*.

Comment: Sure, I added a "practical" example.

Comment: Sayng "I do not understand the example" without explaining what confuses you is not productive. Did you read the relevant Wikipedia pages I pointed to? Those are *directly* related to your question, so the first thing you should od is familiarize yourself with the basic concepts involved.

Comment: In the credit card example, write a new program that runs the charge_credit_card function for all possible inputs. (There are a finite number of `int`s in most languages.) Iff this new program halts (which can be ascertained by **one** call to a halting oracle), then the charge_credit_card function halts on all inputs.

Comment: @ike, the example was meant to have an infinite amount of `int`, quite obviously. Do you really need me to write `BigInt` or some such, or will you then complain that computer memory is finite?

Comment: Computer memory *is* finite. When you're trying to give a "practical" example, you can't allow arbitrarily large inputs.

Comment: Whatever. I told you what the answer to your question was. If you don't want to understand it in good faith, then don't bother us with questions.

Comment: A practical example is, $\overline{HALT}$, the compliment of halt.  This is $\{<M,w>: \text{M doesn't halt on w} \}$  Given an arbitrary program and input to the program, determine if the program doesn't halt.  This problem, along with every other non-recursively enumerable language, doesn't reduce to HALT.

Comment: @tAllan: you should post that as an answer. It beats me what the OP considers "practical", but your example is certainly better than mine.

Answer (score -1):

Predicting a random oracle is not solvable using, possibly, any kind of hypercomputation.

Comment: The OP stated they were looking for "actual, practical, examples".