# Proof that dead code cannot be detected by compilers

Tags: computability, proof-techniques, compilers

I'm planning to teach a winter course on a varying number of topics, one of which is going to be compilers. Now, I came across this problem while thinking of assignments to give throughout the quarter, but it has me stumped so I might use it as an example instead.

```
public class DeadCode {
  public static void main(String[] args) {
     return;
     System.out.println("This line won't print.");
  }
}
```

In the program above, it's obvious that the print statement will never execute because of the `return`. Compilers sometimes give warnings or errors about dead code. For example, the above code will not compile in Java. The javac compiler, however, will not detect all instances of dead code in every program. How would I prove that no compiler can do so?

Comment: What is your background and what is the context you'll be teaching in? To be blunt, I'm mildly worried that you have to ask this, seeing as you are going to teach. But good call asking here!

Comment: [Same question at Stack Overflow](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33266420/why-cant-dead-code-detection-be-fully-solved-by-a-compiler)

Comment: In a programming language that has arbitrary jump instructions (and no, `goto` to a line label doesn't count), it is possible to write code that literally jumps into the middle of an instruction. In the early days of personal computers, this was an often-used tactic to thwart disassemblers, because disassemblers would become confused by the "impossible" jump. Now add self-modifying code (which was also often used earlier, but these days tends to be frowned upon for a variety of reasons) to the mix. Show how dead code detection is impossible with this mix, then work your way up the stack.

Comment: It is entirely possible to mess with the instruction pointers at runtime to skip to a section of compiled code that would previously have been un-reachable. This is an important behavior to check for when auditing security-sensitive code, and is generally only applicable in native code implementations (C/C++), but can be externally forced as well (as in the ShellShock exploit of SSH).

Comment: @MichaelKjörling Dead code detection is impossible even without those considerations.

Comment: From a compiler engineering perspective, it's well understood by everyone that compilers will optimise some things and not optimise others, so it's not just a case of "cannot", it's also a case of "will not". A compiler could optimise sin(x)*sin(x)+cos(x)*cos(x) to 1, but yours almost certainly won't; if you try to evaluate the former, your friendly compiler writer will happily inform you that you will get the generated code that you deserve. It's a far better use of a compiler's time to optimise expressions such as i+1.

Comment: @DavidRicherby I didn't mean that those conditions were what made dead code detection impossible. (If they were, dead code detection would certainly be possible in a large number of languages that do not meet those criteria.) I meant that for a specific example, it might make a good starting point for an explanation of the *why*.

Comment: `BigInteger i = 0; while(isCollatzConjectureTrueFor(i)) i++; printf("Hello world\n");`

Comment: @immibis The question asks for a *proof* that dead code detection is *impossible*. You have given an *example* where correct dead code detection requires solving an open problem in mathematics. That does not *prove* that dead code detection is *impossible*.

Comment: @DavidRicherby Then substitute `isCollatzConjectureTrueFor` for `doesMyFavouriteTuringMachineHaltAfterSteps`.

Comment: @immibis That's computable, assuming that you have one fixed favorite machine.

Answer (score 57):

It all comes from undecidability of the halting problem. Suppose we have a "perfect" dead code function, some Turing Machine M, and some input string x, and a procedure that looks something like this:

```
Run M on input x;
print "Finished running input";
```

If M runs forever, then we delete the print statement, since we will never reach it. If M doesn't run forever, then we need to keep the print statement. Thus, if we have a dead-code remover, it also lets us solve the Halting Problem, so we know there can be no such dead-code remover.

The way we get around this is by "conservative approximation." So, in my Turing Machine example above, we can assume that running M on x might finish, so we play it safe and don't remove the print statement. In your example, we know that no matter which functions do or don't halt, that there's no way we will reach that print statement.

Usually, this is done by constructing a "control-flow graph". We make simplifying assumptions, such as "the end of a while loop is connected to the beginning and the statement after", even if it runs forever or runs only once and doesn't visit both. Similarly, we assume that an if-statement can reach all of its branches, even if in reality some are never used. These kinds of simplifications allow us to remove "obviously dead code" like the example you give, while remaining decidable.

To clarify a few confusions from the comments:

1. > Nitpick: for fixed M, this is always decidable. M has to be the input

   As Raphael says, in my example, we consider the Turing Machine as an input. The idea is that, if we had a perfect DCE algorithm, we would be able to construct the code snippet I give *for any Turing Machine*, and having a DCE would solve the halting problem.
2. > not convinced. return as a blunt statement in a no-branch straight forward execution is not hard to decide. (and my compiler tells me it is capable of figuring this out)

   For the issue njzk2 raises: you are absolutely right, in this case you can determine that there is no way a statement after the return can be reached. This is because it's simple enough that we can describe its unreachability using control-flow graph constraints (i.e. there are no outgoing edges out of a return statement). But there is no perfect dead code eliminator, which eliminates all unused code.
3. > I don't take input-dependent proof for a proof. If there exists such kind of user input that can allow the code to be finite, it's correct for the compiler to assume that following branch is not dead. I can't see what are all these upvotes for, it's both obvious (eg. endless stdin) and wrong.

   For TomášZato: it's not really an input dependent proof. Rather, interpret it as a "forall". It works as follows: assume we have a perfect DCE algorithm. If you give me an arbitrary Turing Machine M and input x, I can use my DCE algorithm to determine whether M halts, by constructing the code snippet above and seeing if the print-statement is removed. This technique, of leaving a parameter arbitrary to prove a forall-statement, is common in math and logic.

   I don't fully understand TomášZato's point about code being finite. Surely the code is finite, but a perfect DCE algorithm must apply to all code, which is an infinte set. Likewise, while the code-itself is finite, the potential sets of input are infinte, as is the potential running-time of the code.

   As for considering the final branch not-dead: it is safe in terms of the "conservative approximation" I talk about, but it's not enough to detect all instances of dead code as the OP asks for.

Consider code like this:

```
while (true)
  print "Hello"
print "goodbye"
```

Clearly we can remove `print "goodbye"` without changing the behavior of the program. Thus, it is dead code. But if there's a different function call instead of `(true)` in the `while` condition, then we don't know if we can remove it or not, leading to the undecidability.

Note that I am not coming up with this on my own. It is a well known result in the theory of compilers. It's discussed in [The Tiger Book](https://www.cs.princeton.edu/~appel/modern/ml/). (You might be able to see where they talk about in in [Google books](https://books.google.ca/books?id=A3yqQuLW5RsC&printsec=frontcover&dq=compiler+construction+in+ML&hl=en&sa=X&redir_esc=y#v=onepage&q=fully&f=false).

Comment: @TomášZato: The dead code eliminator receives an input with both M and x hard-coded; if x is a non-halting input for M, the following print statement is dead code. If the dead code eliminator can correctly decide whether the print is dead, regardless of what M and x values are embedded in its input, it can solve the halting problem. There is no opportunity for a user to provide endless stdin or anything like that.

Comment: @njzk2: We're trying to show it's impossible to build a dead code eliminator that eliminates *all* dead code, not that it's impossible to build a dead code eliminator that eliminates *some* dead code. The print-after-return example can be eliminated easily using control-flow graph techniques, but not all dead code can be eliminated this way.

Comment: @jmite Thanks for your effort and patience, I appreciate it. However your edit made me even more confident that you're wrong. In your second example, you postulate that `while` condition cannot be resolved by compiler at compile time. This again boils down to two options: **(a)** Condition depends on external input -> compiler *must* assume it may or may not be infinite **(b)** Condition depends only on internal variables, known at compile time - [endless loop can be detected](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cycle_detection). It's also worth noting that endless loop example isn't very practical.

Comment: This answer *references* comments. As I read the answer, I need to jump down into the comments, then return to the answer. This is confusing (doubly so when you consider that comments are fragile and may be lost). A self-contained answer would be far easier to read.

Comment: @TomášZato - consider the program that increments a variable $n$ and checks whether or not $n$ is an odd perfect number, terminating only when it finds such a number. Clearly this program does not depend on any external input. Are you asserting that it can easily be determined whether or not this program terminates?

Comment: @GregoryJ.Puleo The OP didn't mention word `easy` or `easily` in his question **a single time.** This is supoposed be computer science, and I expect a rigorous proof, not a proof *by obscurity*. It doesn't mater how hard is it to evaluate it, as long as it's possible, the proof is invalid. And this one is invalid, no matter how many people upvoted it without even thinking about it.

Comment: @TomášZato - sure, let's forget about the word "easy", then. The point is that if we had just a single compiler that could check whether programs like this terminate, then this compiler could solve any open problem in mathematics that can be expressed as "does a given program taking no input ever terminate"? Existence of an odd perfect number is one such problem; other famous ones include the Goldbach Conjecture, the 3n+1 problem; Hadwiger's conjecture. Isn't it a rather strong claim to just *assert* that a program exists that can solve all these problems at one stroke?

Comment: (of course, the real stumbling block here is that such an algorithm would solve the Halting Problem; what I'm presenting here is just a heuristic argument, not a formal one)

Comment: @TomášZato You are mistaken in your understanding of the halting problem. Given a finite Turing Machine $M$, and finite input $x$, it's impossible to determine whether $M$ infinitely loops while running on $x$. I haven't proven this rigorously because it has been proved over and over again, and is a fundamental principle of computer science. There's a nice sketch of the proof [on Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Halting_problem)

Comment: @TomášZato If you're viewing a computer as a finite-memory machine, technically loop detection is possible, but I've got [another answer](http://cs.stackexchange.com/a/32853/2253) where I talk about why it's entirely impractical, and quite useless to think of things that way. (In short, adding a single extra bit of RAM completely invalidates any analysis done this way).

Comment: jmite, please incorporate valid comments into the answer so that the answer stands on its own. Then flag all comments that are obsolete as such so we can clean up. Thanks!

Answer (score 14):

This is a twist on jmite's answer that circumvents the potential confusion about non-termination. I'll give a program that always halts itself, may have dead code but we can not (always) algorithmically decide if it has.

Consider the following class of inputs for the dead-code identifier:

```
simulateMx(n) {
  simulate TM M on input x for n steps
  if M did halt
    return 0
  else
    return 1
}
```

Since `M` and `x` are fixed, `simulateMs` has dead code with `return 0` if and only if `M` does not halt on `x`.

This immediately gives us a reduction from the halting problem to dead-code checking: given TM $M$ as halting-problem instance, create above program with `x` the code of $M$ -- it has dead code if and only if $M$ does not halt on its own code.

Hence, dead-code checking is not computable.

In case you are unfamiliar with reduction as a proof technique in this context, I recommend [our reference material](https://cs.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/599/reference-answers-to-frequently-asked-questions/847#847).

Answer (score 5):

A simple way to demonstrate this kind of property without getting bogged into details is to use the following lemma:

**Lemma:** For any compiler C for a Turing-complete language, there exists a function `undecidable_but_true()` which takes no arguments and returns the boolean true, such that C cannot predict whether `undecidable_but_true()` returns true or false.

Note that the function depends on the compiler. Given a function `undecidable_but_true1()`, a compiler can always be augmented with the knowledge of whether this function returns true or false; but there is always some other function `undecidable_but_true2()` that won't be covered.

**Proof:** by [Rice's theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rice%27s_theorem), the property “this function returns true” is undecidable. Therefore any static analysis algorithm is unable to decide this property for all possible functions.

**Corollary:** Given a compiler C, the following program contains dead code which cannot be detected:

```
if (!undecidable_but_true()) {
    do_stuff();
}
```

---

A note about Java: the Java language mandates that compilers reject certain programs that contain unreachable code, while sensibly mandating that code is provided at all reachable points (e.g. control flow in a non-void function must end with a `return` statement). The language specifies exactly how the unreachable code analysis is performed; if it didn't then it would be impossible to write portable programs. Given a program of the form

```
some_method () {
    <code whose continuation is unreachable>
    // is throw InternalError() needed here?
}
```

it is necessary to specify in which cases the unreachable code must be followed by some other code and in which cases it must not be followed by any code. An example of a Java program that contains code that is unreachable, but not in a way that Java compilers are allowed to notice, comes up in Java 101:

```
String day_of_week(int n) {
    switch (n % 7) {
    case 0: return "Sunday";
    case 1: case -6: return "Monday";
    …
    case 6: case -1: return "Saturday";
    }
    // return or throw is required here, even though this point is unreachable
}
```

Comment: Note that some compilers for some languages may be able to detect that the end of `day_of_week` is unreachable.

Comment: @immibis Yes, for example CS101 students can do it in my experience (though admittedly CS101 students aren't a sound static analyzer, they usually forget about the negative cases). That's part of my point: it's an example of a program with unreachable code that a Java compiler will not detect (at least, may warn about, but may not reject).

Comment: I'm afraid the phrasing of the Lemma is misleading at best, with a tint of wrongness to it. Undecidability only makes sense if you phrase it terms of (infinite) sets of instances. (The compiler *does* produce an answer for every function, and we know that it can not be always correct, but saying that there's a single undecidable instance is off.) Your paragraph between the Lemma and the Proof (which does not quite match the Lemma as stated) tries to fix this, but I think it would be better to formulate a clearly correct lemma.

Comment: @Raphael Uh? No, the compiler need not produce an answer to the question “is this function constant?”. It doesn't need to distinguish “I don't know” from “no” to produce working code, but that's not relevant here since we're only interested in the static analysis part of the compiler, not in the code translation part. I don't understand what you find misleading or incorrect about the statement of the lemma — unless your point is that I should write “static analyzer” instead of “compiler”?

Comment: The statement sounds like "undecidability means that there is an instance that can not be solved", which is wrong. (I know you don't mean to say that, but that's how it can read to the unwary/novices, imho.)

Answer (score 3):

jmite's answer applies to whether the program will ever exit a calculation--just because it's infinite I wouldn't call the code after it dead.

However, there's another approach: A problem for which there is an answer but it's unknown:

```
public void Demo()
{
  if (Chess.Evaluate(new Chessboard(), int.MaxValue) != 0)
    MessageBox.Show("Chess is unfair!");
  else
    MessageBox.Show("Chess is fair!");
}

public class chess
{
  public Int64 Evaluate(Chessboard Board, int SearchDepth)
  {
  ...
  }
}
```

This routine without a doubt **does** contain dead code--the function will return an answer that executes one path but not the other.  Good luck finding it, though!  My memory is no theoretical computer can solve this within the lifespan of the universe.

In more detail:

The `Evaluate()` function computes which side wins a chess games if both sides play perfectly (with maximum search depth).

Chess evaluators normally look ahead at every possible move some specified depth and then attempt to score the board at that point (sometimes expanding certain branches farther as looking halfway through an exchange or the like can produce a very skewed perception.)  Since the actual maximum depth is 17695 half-moves the search is exhaustive, it will traverse every possible chess game.  Since all the games end there's no issue of trying to decide how good a position each board is (and thus no reason to look at the board evaluation logic--it will never be called), the result is either a win, a loss or a draw.  If the result is a draw the game is fair, if the result is not a draw it's an unfair game.  To expand it a bit we get:

```
public Int64 Evaluate(Chessboard Board, int SearchDepth)
{
  foreach (ChessMove Move in Board.GetPossibleMoves())
    {
      Chessboard NewBoard = Board.MakeMove(Move);
      if (NewBoard.Checkmate()) return int.MaxValue;
      if (NewBoard.Draw()) return 0;
      if (SearchDepth == 0) return NewBoard.Score();
      return -Evaluate(NewBoard, SearchDepth - 1);
    }
}
```

Note, also, that it will be virtually impossible for the compiler to realize that Chessboard.Score() is dead code.  A knowledge of the rules of chess allows us humans to figure this out but to figure this out you have to know that MakeMove can never increase the piece count and that Chessboard.Draw() will return true if the piece count remains static for too long.

Note that the search depth is in half-moves, not whole moves.  This is normal for this sort of AI routine as it's an O(x^n) routine--adding one more search ply has a major effect on how long it takes to run.

Comment: You assume that a checking algorithm would have to perform the calculation. A common fallacy! No, you don't get to assume *anything* about how a checker would work, otherwise you can not refute its existence.

Comment: The question requests a _proof_ that it is _impossible_ to detect dead code. Your post contains an example of a case where you _suspect_ it would be _difficult_ to detect dead code. That isn't an answer to the question at hand.

Comment: I don't understand what this is trying to prove. If there's an arbitrary calculation in the `Evaluate` the compiler either sees it and can try to decide it or doesn't see it and then it must assume all branches are valid, depending on implementation of the hidden function.

Comment: How could the checker find the answer faster than actually doing the calculation?

Comment: @LorenPechtel I don't know, but that's not a proof. See also [here](http://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/367/how-can-it-be-decidable-whether-pi-has-some-sequence-of-digits); a cleaner example of your misconception.

Comment: If it helps, consider that there's nothing theoretically stopping someone from running their compiler for more than the lifetime of the universe; the only limitation is practicality. A decidable problem is a decidable problem, even if it's in the complexity class NONELEMENTARY.

Comment: @Pseudonym Solving chess on the fixed, standard 8x8 board is in $\mathrm{TIME}[O(1)]\,$!

Comment: This answer is full of misconceptions.  The question asks for a proof, but this answer doesn't contain a proof.  It merely asserts that it will be "virtually impossible" for a compiler to figure out whether this is dead code, but it does not provide any proof of this fact (not to mention that "virtually impossible" isn't the same as "impossible").  Maybe next decade someone will figure out that chess is a first-player win, and then it wouldn't be impossible at all for a compiler to decide whether it's dead code.

Comment: In other words, this answer is at best a heuristic intended to show why it's probably not easy to build a compiler that detects all dead code -- but it's not a proof of impossibility.  This kind of example *might* be useful as a way to build intuition for students, but it is not a proof.   By presenting itself as a proof, it does a disservice.  The answer should be edited to state that it is an intuition-building example but *not* a proof of impossibility.

Comment: @DavidRicherby, true! But I didn't intend to imply that solving Chess-type problems are NONELEMENTARY. Actually, pretty much any problem involving evaluating the positions in arbitrary-size generalisations of chess is probably in PSPACE.

Comment: @Pseudonym I'm not sure about PSPACE: determining whether either player has a winning strategy in generalized chess (i.e., on an $n\times n$) without the 50-move rule is EXPTIME-complete. I've no particular intuition if including the 50-move rule would bring the complexity down to PSPACE. (But I realise the main thrust of your comment wasn't to pin it down to a specific complexity class.)

Comment: @D.W. "This kind of example might be useful as a way to build intuition for students" -- intuition for computability? How could it, given that it uses a *wrong* intuition?

Comment: @Raphael, fair enough.  No, I didn't mean that it provides intuition for undecidability -- I meant that it provides intuition for why it doesn't seem easy to detect all instances of dead code.  This is different from impossibility, of course.  It's a pedagogical decision whether this will help students or hurt them; I could imagine reasonable arguments on both sides.  I'm just trying to articulate how this answer could be better and try to suggest one way that the answer could have some value, if it were edited to more clearly indicate that it's not a proof of impossibility and why.

Comment: @D.W. While it doesn't prove it in a theoretical sense it shows there are things which a compiler can not reasonably figure out if they are dead or not.  Since compilers are a matter of what's practical to do it feels like a proof to me.

Comment: @LorenPechtel, *"While it doesn't prove it in a theoretical sense it shows there are things which a compiler can not reasonably figure out if they are dead or not."* - That's reasonable, but your answer should *state that* explicitly, to avoid confusion.  *"Since compilers are a matter of what's practical to do it feels like a proof to me."* - That's not what is meant by the word proof.  The word proof has an accepted meaning, and it's not that.

Answer (score -3):

I think in a computing course, the notion of dead code is interesting in the context of understanding the difference between compile time and run time!

A compiler can determine when you've got code that can in no compile-time scenario ever be traversed, but it cannot do so for runtime. a simple while-loop with user input for the loop-break test shows that.

If a compiler could actually determine runtime dead code (i.e. discern Turing complete) then there's an argument that the code never needs be run, because the job's already done!

If nothing else, the existence of code that passes compile-time dead code checks illustrates the need for pragmatic bounds-checking on inputs and general coding hygiene (in the real world of real projects.)

Comment: The question asks for a proof that it is impossible to detect dead code. You have not answered that question.

Comment: Also, your assertion that "A compiler can determine when you've got code that can in no compile-time scenario ever be traversed" is incorrect and directly contradicts what the question asks you to prove.

Comment: @David Richerby, I think you may be misreading me.  I'm not suggesting that compile-time checking can find ALL dead code, quite definitely not.  I'm suggesting that there is a subset of the set of all dead code that is discernable at compile time.    If I write:   if(true==false){ print("something");}, that print statement will be discernable at compile time to be dead code.  Do you disagree that this is a counterexample to your assertion?

Comment: Sure, you can determine *some* dead code. But if you're going to say "determine when [you have dead code]" with no qualifications then that, to me, means find all the dead code, not just some of it.