# the problems that could exist if halting problem is solved

Tags: complexity-theory, halting-problem

What problems might exist if halting problem is solved. If there exist an oracle that can compute whether a given machine halts or not then what would be problems that could exists if such oracle is there

Comment: I think this can solve your question: https://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/32845/why-really-is-the-halting-problem-so-important

Comment: You appear to misunderstand the halting problem. It is not an unsolved problem in mathematics that we're striving to solve. Its unsolvability is a well-known, proven mathematical result, a property of mechanical computation, namely, the fact that there exist problems for which no mechanical computation can solve all cases.

Answer (score 1):

"Exists" is a weird word to use here; I assume you're asking about what problems would be *solvable* if we were suddenly able to solve the halting problem.

Phrasing things in terms of sets of natural numbers for simplicity (as is the general approach here) you're asking for a characterization of the sets which are [Turing reducible](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Turing_reduction) to [$0'$](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Turing_jump). It turns out that this is a very robust notion. For example, the following three properties of a set $X$ are equivalent:

- $X\le_T0'$.
- $X$ is [limit computable](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Computation_in_the_limit#Limit_lemma): there is a computable total function $f(x,s)$ such that for each $n\in\mathbb{N}$ we have $\lim_{s\rightarrow\infty}f(n,s)$ exists and is $1$ iff $n\in X$ and is $0$ otherwise.
- $X$ is [$\Delta^0_2$-definable](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Post%27s_theorem): there are formulas $\varphi_1(z)\equiv\forall x\exists y\theta_1(x,y,z)$ and $\varphi_2(z)\equiv\forall x\exists y\theta_2(x,y,z)$ where $\theta_1,\theta_2$ use only bounded quantifiers such that $$X=\{n:\varphi_1(n)\}=\{n:\neg\varphi_2(n)\}.$$

Meanwhile, some problems which are **not** Turing reducible to the halting problem include:

- Does a given Turing machine halt on all inputs?
- Do two Turing machines accept the same language?
- Is a given c.e. set actually computable?

The first two have Turing degree $0''$, while the third has degree $0'''$. It's worth noting that while there are sets which are not "iterations of the halting problem," and in particular there are always lots of degrees between ${\bf d}$ and ${\bf d'}$, there is strong evidence that no "natural" examples of such sets. (There's also a lot of stuff "off to the side" - for example, the set of problems which are Turing-*incomparable* with $0'$ has [full measure](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Almost_everywhere) and is [comeager](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Meagre_set).)